# Adding flags to highcharts (not highstock) dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/sH777/) and I'd like to implement that after the series had been created. often I let the user update the chart, I do this by sending array of float to the setData function of the series.

for example:

```
//Build the area values
for (var i = 0; i < area.length; i++)
{
    areaValues.push(parseFloat(area[i]));
}

chart.series[2].setData(areaValues,false);
chart.redraw();
```

Is there any way to add flags before the redraw without recreating the chart?

Comment: Are you asking if flags are possible with Highcharts instead of Highstock?  It doesn't seem to be part of the highcharts api.

Comment: Yeah, apparently it is possible but only if you "copy paste" some parts from highstock. the suggestion I received from the Highcharts team is to use scatter chart instead. and that's acutely works really nice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your data format - for flags should be this one:

```
{
    x: 9,
    title: 'I',
    text: 'Information'
}
```

Not just a number. You can achieve what you need in a two ways, or by setting new data, or adding new series, see example of both: http://jsfiddle.net/sH777/180/

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately I wanted to do this with Highcharts and not Highstock (I have license only for Highcharts). 

I ended using the developer's suggestion to use scatter series as the "flags" and it works grate. hope it may help anyone in the future.

Comment: Yes, indeed, you can use scatter series to achieve that. However, Flags are not part of Highcharts. To use Flags, you need Highstock license, check [FAQ](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=13701)

Comment: @PawełFus I have the same scenario as displayed in your jsfiddle. But you see when you hide the series by clicking on the legend, the Flag gets dropped to the xaxis, i am trying to figure out, how to hide the flag when the series is hidden. Any ideas?

Comment: You can connect series to one legend item using [series.linkedTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.linkedTo), see example: http://jsfiddle.net/sH777/340/