# Howto combine Highstock (Highcharts) 'addPoint' function with flags

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, highcharts, graph-visualization

Using the Highstock (Highcharts) library, 
I'm wondering, how do I combine **A)** adding flags as in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/flags-shapes/) (or see ***fig.1***) with **B)** dynamically updating data, using the ***addPoint*** function (ex: `series.addPoint([x, y], true, true)` [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)). There doesn't seem to be a facility for it in the ***addPoint*** function.

```
series : [{
                name : 'USD to EUR',
                data : data,
                id : 'dataseries'
            },
            {
                type : 'flags',
                data : [{
                    x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 25),
                    title : 'H',
                    text : 'Euro Contained by Channel Resistance'
                }],
                onSeries : 'dataseries',
                shape : 'circlepin',
                width : 16
            }]
```

***fig.1***

I have taken a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302908/adding-flags-to-highcharts-not-highstock-dynamically). But is seems to add a flag on an existing dataset. Can I add a data point, and an associated flag at the same time?

Any help's appreciated.

Thanks

***=== EDIT ===>***

@Sebastian-Bochan

Thanks for responding, and for the working example. However, for some reason, ***addPoint*** is not working for my setup.

So take a look at this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twashing/cgYm2/)**. What I do is i) setup an initial graph with a call to `(chart-fill …)`, then ii) call `(chart-increment …)` which adds 1 point, then immediately tries to add 1 flag on that point. The part that isn't working is `(-> ($ selector) (.highcharts) (.-series) (nth 9) (.addPoint { :x 1234567 :title "fubar"} true false))`. This isn't adding the flag as I'd expect.

I have 11 Series overlaid on top of 5 graphs. This includes one series of type "flag". I thought, maybe with so many Series, there was a problem referencing one of them. But if I look into my series, I can see that the flag is indeed the 9th one.

I'm also using Clojurescript code. But I don't think that's an issue, as the graph otherwise renders properly. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/pGpU7/2/

```
 chart.series[0].addPoint([Date.UTC(2012, 1, 5),2],false);

        chart.series[1].addPoint({
                x: Date.UTC(2012, 1, 3),
                title: 'On series'
            },true);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. But this still isn't working for my setup. See my abouve edit.